# Simple multithreading and synchronization problems in MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, windows

I use a worker thread for some data processing in my MFC project. In the thread-controlling function, it needs to use some parameters (declared as member variables) to the data-processing. I use a sub-dialog (which is triggered by a menu item and contains a few edit controls) to change the values of the parameters, that the user inputs are first stored in a `struct`, which is then used in the thread controlling function when needed. In order to prevent data-corruption, I also use Mutex to sync the worker thread and main thread, since both of them need to access the shared resource `m_structBlkContSimPara` (the `struct` that stores parameter values).

```
/*the following code is in my MFC Dlg Project head file*/

struct RecExtractParam {
    bool bMod;

    float fSimBlkShpWt;
    float fSimGrPosWt;
    float fSimGrTxtAttWt;
    float fSimGrTypesWt;
    float fDataUnitGroupSimThld;
    float fVertDistThld;

RecExtractParam() {
    bMod = false;
    fSimBlkShpWt = 0;
    fSimGrPosWt = 0;
    fSimGrTxtAttWt = 0;
    fSimGrTypesWt = 0;
    fDataUnitGroupSimThld = 0;
    fVertDistThld = 0;
}};

RecExtractParam m_structBlkContSimPara;

// parameters for some data processing
float m_fSimBlkShpWt;
float m_fSimGrPosWt;
float m_fSimGrTxtAttWt;
float m_fSimGrTypesWt;
float m_fDataUnitGroupSimThld;
float m_fVertDistThld;

CMutex m_Mutex;

afx_msg void OnToolsBlockContentSimilarityThreshold();

static UINT RecExtractThreadCtrlFunc(LPVOID pParam);

UINT DoThreadProc();

// button clicked handler for launching data processing 

void CXMLDOMFromVCDlg::OnBnClickedDataRecExtractButton()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    // some code for other processing
    // start the thread for data record extraction

    AfxBeginThread(RecExtractThreadCtrlFunc, this);

    // some code for other processing
}

// menu item command handler for parameter inputs

void CXMLDOMFromVCDlg::OnToolsBlockContentSimilarityThreshold()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    // CBlkContSimThldDlg is a sub-dialog for user input
    CBlkContSimThldDlg dlgBlkContSimThld(this);

    if (dlgBlkContSimThld.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        CSingleLock singleLock(&m_Mutex);
        // try to capture the shared resource
        singleLock.Lock();
        m_structBlkContSimPara.bMod = true;
        m_structBlkContSimPara.fDataUnitGroupSimThld =  dlgBlkContSimThld.m_fDlgBlkContSimThld;
        m_structBlkContSimPara.fSimBlkShpWt = dlgBlkContSimThld.m_fDlgGrShpWt;
        m_structBlkContSimPara.fSimGrPosWt = dlgBlkContSimThld.m_fDlgGrPosWt;
        m_structBlkContSimPara.fSimGrTxtAttWt = dlgBlkContSimThld.m_fDlgGrTxtAttWt;
        m_structBlkContSimPara.fSimGrTypesWt = dlgBlkContSimThld.m_fDlgGrContTypeWt;
        m_structBlkContSimPara.fVertDistThld = dlgBlkContSimThld.m_fDlgGrVertDistThld;
        singleLock.Unlock();
   }
}

// thread controlling function

UINT CXMLDOMFromVCDlg::RecExtractThreadCtrlFunc(LPVOID pParam)
{
    CXMLDOMFromVCDlg* pDlg = (CXMLDOMFromVCDlg*)pParam;

    return pDlg->DoThreadProc();
}

UINT CXMLDOMFromVCDlg::DoThreadProc()
{
    // Create object for Single Lock
    CSingleLock singleLock(&m_Mutex);
    // try to capture the shared resource
    singleLock.Lock(); 
    // use the shared resource m_structBlkContSimPara
    if(m_structBlkContSimPara.bMod)
    {
        m_fSimBlkShpWt = m_structBlkContSimPara.fSimBlkShpWt;
        m_fSimGrPosWt = m_structBlkContSimPara.fSimGrPosWt;
        m_fSimGrTxtAttWt = m_structBlkContSimPara.fSimGrTxtAttWt;
        m_fSimGrTypesWt = m_structBlkContSimPara.fSimGrTypesWt;
        m_fDataUnitGroupSimThld = m_structBlkContSimPara.fDataUnitGroupSimThld;
        m_fVertDistThld = m_structBlkContSimPara.fVertDistThld;
        m_structBlkContSimPara.bMod = false;
    }
    // After we done, let other threads use m_structBlkContSimPara
    singleLock.Unlock();
    /*some code for data processing*/
 }
```

I am new to multithreading and synchronization.  Is my code correct?  If not, what should I do to improve it?